# Why is pip always outputting warnings?

Tags: terminal, pip

Why is pip always outputting warnings when installing packages? For instance, I just installed nodeenv and got a bunch of these:

```
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.pyc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.swp'
```

This is not a problem, the packages I install works fine. I'm just curious to why these warnings occur, what they mean and if they somehow can be hidden without suffocating important errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt do that for me...   and looking at the source I don't think it will for anyone in the future.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/320a07fce558f2ba126a34279c5ea11e80b08594), these warnings were removed in Dec 2014.  It would appear that they would have been triggered for cases where a manifest directive was overly cautious and excluded files that had not actually been included.

Comment: Really digging out the old ones huh? :)

Comment: Just happened to see this when looking through unanswered questions.